# Syntax request: "While" syntax for parsing arrays of JSON strings (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba

I am working to get my code to loop through arrays of JSON strings (of same format) until it reaches the end of the arrays (i.e., no strings left). I need the code to recognize it has reached the end by identifying that a certain identifier (present in every set) does not have additional information in the next array. So I believe I am looking for "while" syntax that says "while this identifier has content" proceed parsing the JSON according to the below code. My existing code works for array of strings for which I know the length - unfortunately the lengths are variable therefore I need flexible syntax to adjust with the lengths (i.e., "For 0 to n" doesn't work every time).

The JSON code I am parsing is in this format:

```
{"id":1,"prices":[{"name":"expressTaxi","cost":{"base":"USD4.50","fareType":
"time_plus_distance","cancelFee":"USD10.00","minimumAmt":"USD8.00","perMinute":"USD1.50",
"perDistanceUnit":"USD3.00"}}] 
''note that this could have multiple arrays embedded. That is, from the "name" key to 
''the "perDistanceUnit" key would all repeat, with different value pairs. 
''The number of "name" to "perDistanceUnit" arrays is unknown.
```

Here the identifier structure I'd like to augment with some type of while loop (the "i" is the index number depending on the # of loop in the yet to be implemented "while" loop).

```
Json("prices")(i)("name")
```

So ideally looking for something like:

```
"While Json("prices")(i)("name") has information" then proceed on....
```

Please note again, everything works when I know the length -- just looking for a small syntax update, thank you! UPDATE: full code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getJSON()
sheetCount = 1
i = 1
urlArray = Array("URL1", “URL2”, “URL3”)

Dim MyRequest As Object: Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim MyUrls: MyUrls = urlArray
Dim k As Long
Dim Json As Object

For k = LBound(MyUrls) To UBound(MyUrls)
    With MyRequest
        .Open "GET", MyUrls(k)
        .Send
        Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.ResponseText)
       ''[where I’d like some type of While statement checking into the below line for content]
        Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 1) = Json("prices")(i)("name")
        Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 2) = Json("prices")(i)("cost")("base")
        i = i + 1
   End With
sheetCount = sheetCount + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to show your existing code, including how you're parsing the JSON

Comment: @TimWilliams updated full code above.

Comment: `Debug.Print Json("prices").Count` should tell you how many elements there are.  Maybe you could post a larger sample of your JSON?

Comment: @TimWilliams I added a full sample of the JSON, with comments for additional context.

Comment: There's still nothing to loop over in that sample: it's just a single object inside `prices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with the library you're using, bit it seems like it converts objects (items enclosed in `{ }`) to dictionary objects, and array (things enclosed in `[ ]`) to Collections.

Depending on the structure of the parsed JSON, these objects may be nested: ie. one element in a dictionary may be a Collection(array).

Luckily for you both, of these object types have a `Count` property you can use to iterate over them (and the dictionary type also has a "keys" collection).

So to loop over each "price":

```
Dim i As Long, p As Object

For i = 1 To Json("prices").Count
    Set p = Json("prices")(i)
    Debug.Print p("name"), p("cost")("base"), p("cost")("fareType")
Next i
```

Comment: SUPER HELPFUL - thank YOU for the help, @TimWilliams! Now I just need to print these to the correct cells/sheets!